# Imported images to Photo turn grey/gray after loading

Tags: jpeg, imac, iphoto

Importing combined **jpeg /raw** images from my **Panasonic GX7** to my **iMac**  using Photo seemed at first to be going well but then the full images started being covered over by grey/gray rectangles of varying sizes.

A few images were not affected at all but most were partially covered and some totally. This covering happened over a few minutes.

(I had previously downloaded a lot of images from a **Panasonic LX100** without a problem.) I know the images are fine because I can view them in my camera and they initially appear intact on my computer also.

Comment: Sounds like corrupt files, but I'm not sure why. You haven't described your import process. For instance, are you plugging in through USB or are you removing the memory card? The memory card could be going bad and the photos could be corrupt. There are usually two different images, a thumbnail and the main photo. The thumbnail may be intact but once the full image loads it is corrupt.

Comment: Thank you for your response and sorry for my delay. My import process was by USB cable from my camera. I also tried importing them first to Dropbox but with the same result. Both the thumbnail and the imported photos look fine at first then the imported photos start blocking out before my eyes. As I said they are fine in my camera display.

Answer (score -1):

Fact that you can view them fine on the camera doesn't mean a lot. It is probably showing you embedded previews.

I'm not a Mac guy, but I have seen it with Windows. Thumbnails show fine initially. Later it appears corrupt. Again it's the embedded previews. Once it loads / renders actual data images look corrupt.

Is it possible for you to post an example somewhere. Needs to be the original file showing the issue (not down sized etc.).